# Purchased two MS hosted parallel jobs but build is still timing out at 60 minutes

Tags: azure-pipelines

As per the instructions in the documentation, I purchased two parallel jobs to remove the 60-minute timeout and to have multiple jobs running in the same pipeline but I still timeout at 60 minutes, is there anything I should do after purchasing the MS hosted parallel jobs?

> Private project: One free parallel job that can run for up to 60 minutes each time, until you've used 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per month. You can pay for additional capacity per parallel job. Paid parallel jobs remove the monthly time limit and allow you to run each job for up to 360 minutes (6 hours). Buy Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the timeoutInMinutes attribute to the job (to take full advantage of your purchase);

```
jobs:
- job: build
  timeoutInMinutes: 360
  steps:
  - pwsh: Write-Host "Really long build task here..."
    timeoutInMinutes: 100
```

or the deploymentJob;

```
jobs:
- deployment: deploy
  environment: prod
  timeoutInMinutes: 360
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - pwsh: Write-Host "Really long deployment task here..."
          timeoutInMinutes: 100
```

Below snippet from the [official docs on timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#timeouts);

> - Forever on self-hosted agents
> - For 360 minutes (6 hours) on  Microsoft-hosted agents with a public project and public repository
> - For 60 minutes on Microsoft-hosted agents with a private project or private repository (unless additional capacity is paid for)

You can also add timeoutInMinutes [on the individual tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#controloptions) (as also shown above) but that value will be overridden by the timeoutInMinutes specified in the job/deploymentJob.

Comment: I had the timeoutminutes under the steps but not under the jobs, that fixed the issue, thank you!